How to bypass Cloudflare using Playwright
I'm creating a webscraping program in Python that bypasses Cloudflare authentication like the checkbox. Problem is that the program is unable to search for the <iframe> where the checkbox resides
async def run(playwright: Playwright):
    args = []

    #disable navigator.webdriver:true flag
    args.append("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    browser = await playwright.firefox.launch(headless=False, args=args)
    context = await browser.new_context()
    page = await context.new_page()
    await page.goto(url)
    print("Navigated to:", url)

    await asyncio.sleep(30)

    # Wait for the iframe containing the CAPTCHA to load
    iframe = await page.wait_for_selector("iframe[title='Widget containing a Cloudflare security challenge']")
    captcha_frame = await iframe.content_frame()

    # Click the CAPTCHA checkbox
    checkbox = await captcha_frame.wait_for_selector("input[type='checkbox']")
    await checkbox.click()
    print("CAPTCHA checkbox clicked.")

    await asyncio.sleep(10)

    await browser.close()

There is no error to be found but it's won't pass the Cloudflare checkbox unless I manually check it myself.
I tried to search for the <iframe> and expects the program to automate the checking of the checkbox of the Cloudflare authentication. But the result was the opposite, the program cannot find the <iframe>.

Just search "How cloudflare captcha works" on Google.
And search "bypassing cloudflare captcha"

Cloudflare captcha is not just checking the "is checkbox checked" value. It also checks your user-agent, ip, cookies, and other specific http headers. If you check the checkbox manually, headers will be created automatically. But if you use playwright, you should set headers manually. To act like you're not a bot.
Also, captcha with checkbox checks your cursor movement until captcha checkbox click.
Reference:
https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/bots/how-captchas-work/

This reCAPTCHA test takes into account the movement of the user's cursor as it approaches the checkbox. Even the most direct motion by a human has some amount of randomness on the microscopic level: tiny unconscious movements that bots can't easily mimic. If the cursor's movement contains some of this unpredictability, then the test decides that the user is probably legitimate. The reCAPTCHA also may assess the cookies stored by the browser on a user device and the device's history in order to tell if the user is likely to be a bot.
If the test is still unable to determine whether or not the user is a human, it may present an additional challenge, such as the image recognition test described above. However, most of the time the user's cursor movements, cookies, and device history are conclusive enough.

